# SQL Modeling in Map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to model SQL query like **select distinct (col1) from table where col2= value2** in map reduce. The logic I am using is that each mapper will check for where clause and if the match found, it will emit where clause value as a key and col1 as value. Based on default hash function, all output will go to the same reducer as key used value from where clause. There in the reducer, I can exclude duplicate and emit distinct values. Is this correct approach?

Is this a correct approach to implement this?

Note: Data for this query is in the CSV file.

Comment: Did you try [Hive](https://hive.apache.org)?

Comment: I need to do it using map reduce framework. Logic I am using is each mapper will check for where clause and if match will emit where clause as key and col1 as value. Based on default hash function, all output will go to same reducer. There in reducer I can exclude duplicate and emit distinct values . is this correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//MAPPER pseudo code
public static class DistinctMapper extends  Mapper<Object, Text, Text, NullWritable> {
        private Text col1 = new Text();
        private Text col2 = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // Logic to extract columns
            String C1  = extractColumn(value);
            String C2  = extractColumn(value);


            if (C2 != 'WhereCluaseValue') {  // filter value
                return;
            }
            // Mapper output key to the distinct column value
            col1.set(C1);
            // Mapper value as NULL
            context.write(col1, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

//REDUCER pseudo code
public static class DistinctReducer extends Reducer<Text, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // distinct column with a null value
            //Here we are not concerned about the list of values
            context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
        }
}
```